# PrintForm Query in C#

Tags: c#

I have a print button in form 1, when i click that, I should be able to print another form say form 2(This form has the basic layout of the page to be printed). Can anyone please tell me as to how to make this reference to form 2 in the form 1 print button event handler? Is there any need to use printform component in both the forms?

When I tried to do this, It was throwing an exception.

Comment: @ Boo all I could do is to have print button in form 2, for which I could generate print and printpreview for form 2. I don't want the print button in form 2 in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

so put the button in Form1..
in the button click handler:

```
using (Form1 dialog = new Form1) {
  // Do whatever you need to do here to print.
}
```